# Understanding the Mechanics and Functionality of Spy Apps in android

Tags: android

I'm an android developer I just want to know how spy apps get access social media apps like WhatsApp, Snapchat...  without root?
i just want to know the logic behind this how these spy apps (like mspy,umobix and others...) works ?